What's the proper way to use decorators which defined and used withing the same class?
I want to create a class method (let's call it BaseClass) that has 2 functions where the first function is used as a decorator on the second function.
The simplification of my code looks like this:
class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id=id

    def write_log(self, log):
        def decorator_func(initial_func):
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                print(f"{self.id}: {log}")
                return initial_func(*args, **kwargs)
            return wrapper
        return decorator_func

    @write_log("This is a log.")
    def my_method(self):
        print(f"This is a test.")

test = BaseClass()
test.my_method(2)

So if I will do:
test = BaseClass()
test.my_method(2)

I'm expecting it to print the following output:
6: This is a log.
This is a test.

But it fails with this error:
TypeError: write_logs() missing 1 required positional argument: 'log'

If I will add 'self' before the decorator call it will fail with "NameError: name 'self' is not defined"
    @self.write_logs("This is a log.")
    def my_method(self):
        print(f"This is a test.")

What am I doing wrong here?

You have no self defined and write_logs doesn't use it. Why do you use it as a parameter then?

This question is similar to: Python decorators in classes. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You're using it in a context where self doesn't exist. But the decorator doesn't need to be inside the class body. wrapper will be the decorated instance method so it could take a self arg.

I need the decorator method to be part of the class so it will be able to use the self.id variable.
In the similar question there was no class variable being used inside the decorator so it could be moved outside of the class as a solution. But this solution doesn't work for me here.
